# Flutter question list with more then one correct and wrong answers

Tags: dart

My problem is that i want to create a Quiz app (learning App) with Flutter and Dart and lots of questions. But I don't know how to make a list with lots of wrong an correct answers.

There are several types of question cards one of them have 5 answers and the another one have 4 answers. The capacity of my Quiz are 1250 questions its more like a learning App.

A other problem is that I have been searching for a easy way to create this question cards because there a lot of question.

Is the language Dart the right one or exists better solutions? I add the code of my quiz page and three pictures of my other code.

**This is an image that shows the quizmodel**
[image: This is a picture that shows the quizmodel]

**This image shows the quiz questions**
[image: This picture shows the quiz questions]

**This image shows the Question Controller**
[image: This image shows the Question Controller]

The following code are not the full code of my program, but the logic that i tried:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:percent_indicator/circular_percent_indicator.dart';
import 'package:quizapp/layout/widgets.dart';
import 'package:quizapp/logic/questionController.dart';
import 'package:quizapp/logic/questions.dart';
import 'package:quizapp/model/quizmodel.dart';

class Quizpage extends StatefulWidget {
  const Quizpage({super.key});

  @override
  State<Quizpage> createState() => _QuizpageState();
}

class _QuizpageState extends State<Quizpage> {
  int currentLevel = 1;
  late QuestionModel currentQuestion;
  late List<String> answers;

  @override
  void initState() {
    currentQuestion = loadQuestion(1);
    
    answers = getRandomQuestionList(
      currentQuestion.wrongAnswers,
      currentQuestion.correctAnswers,
    );
    
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: customAppBar("Quiz"),
      body: Container(
        decoration: const BoxDecoration(
            image: DecorationImage(
                image: AssetImage("assets/background.png"),
                fit: BoxFit.fitHeight)),
        child: Center(
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                const Spacer(
                  flex: 2,
                ),
                Text(currentQuestion.question,
                    style: const TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.black,
                        fontStyle: FontStyle.normal,
                        fontSize: 24)),

                const Spacer(),
                // Example 16
                Text(
                  "Aktueller Vortschritt:",
                  style: normalTextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                ),
                CircularPercentIndicator(
                  radius: 60.0,
                  lineWidth: 10.0,
                  percent: 0.1,
                  center: const Text("10%"),
                  progressColor: Colors.green,
                ),
                const Spacer(),
                answerCard(answers[0], context),
                answerCard(answers[1], context),
                answerCard(answers[2], context),
                answerCard(answers[3], context),
                answerCard(answers[4], context),
                const Spacer()
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Please fix your code so it looks readable. I have no idea how this code is suppose to be structured.

Comment: I improved it I hope it makes more sense now.